# Reversing x-axis scale in ListPlot3D

Tags: plotting, graphics, graphics3d, scaling

I am trying to reverse the x-axis using [`ScalingFunctions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ScalingFunctions.html) but it's not working. I have a 3D plot with x, y and z scale in increasing order, but I want the x-axis to be in reverse order. How can I go about it?

Comment: What do you mean by "reverse the x axis"?  Please provide your code that attempts the solution along with data so people may help.

Comment: Here is my code:    ListPlot3D[Vp2aa, PlotRange -> All, 
 ColorFunction -> Function[{Sw, \[Phi], Vp2aa}, Hue[Vp2aa]], 
 AxesLabel -> {"\[Phi]", "Sw", "Vp2aa"}, 
 PlotLegends -> BarLegend[{Hue, {0, 6000}}]]. My x-axis range from 0 to 100 but I want it to range from 100 to 0 i.e. starting from 100 and not 0

Comment: Do you mean "\[Phi]" in places where you write "[Phi]"?  It is possible that the backslash was removed - it was removed from my writing this too.  I'm also confused as to whether Vp2aa is the z-axis value or the data.  If it is just the z-axis, don't you need more to plot?  Meaning all values.  May we see the data (or subset of the data) you wish to plot?

Comment: Vp2aa = Simplify[
   Table[Sqrt[(
    Kd + ((1 - (Kd/Ko)^2)/(\[Phi]/Kf + (1 - \[Phi])/Ko - Kd/
       Ko^2)) + (4/
       3 *\[G*(1 - (\[Phi]/\[Phi2]))))/(((1 - \[Phi])*\[Ko) + (\
\[Phi]*Sw*\[Rho]w) + ((1 - Sw)* \[Rho]a))], {Sw, 0, 1, 0.01}, {\[Phi],
      0, 0.4, 0.01}]];

Comment: Unfortunately, copy-paste of your code for Vp2aa doesn't work.  Please consider adding it to your original post.  You might try using  "```" to start the code block and the same to end the code block.

Comment: Does adding `ScalingFunctions -> {"Reverse", None, None}` to options of your `ListPlot3D` work for you?

Comment: Thank you, Alx. I tried your suggestion but it didn't work but I used ScalingFunctions -> { None, "Reverse", None} and it worked.